# How to search value in data field transaction

Tags: contract-development, transactions

I need to look for a value in the data field of a transaction and to know which transactions contain the desired value.
Let me explain with an example.
In the data field of a transaction there is for example the variable username which has value "testusername".
How can I search among all transactions only those that have the variable with username "testusername"?
Do you know how I could do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, here is something you can try:

```
async function getCount() {
    // get block with transaction object
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(2535330, true);
    // get block transactions and loop through each transaction
    block.transactions.forEach(tx => {
        // log what is input actually
        console.log(tx.input);
        // 0xd69f13bb0000000000000000000000004171b9e0267d09799a0d68e83cb0217988f9fe3a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026afa0
        // the end of above is value sent in the transaction
        // decode this value using web3.utils
        let value = tx.input.slice(tx.input.length - 6, tx.input.length)
        // covert this value to number
        let numValue = web3.utils.toDecimal("0x" + tx.input.slice(tx.input.length - 6, tx.input.length))
        console.log(value);
        console.log(numValue);

        // use if statement to filter it out
        if (value == '26afa0') {
            console.log(tx);

        }
    })
}

getCount()
```

hope it will help.